# How to display bootstrap modal on page load in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, components, react-functional-component

How to display bootstrap 5 modal in react using useEffect hook when page load in react js. And get user name in modal and display on screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can set visibility state to true in useEffect
just like

```
useEffect(()=>{
    setModalVisiblity(true);
}, []);
```